# Changing back to default homedir

Tags: key

Today I encountered an error after trying to import a gpg key as following:

```
E:\tdp\gpg>gpg --import SA000146.asc

gpg: keyblock resource `c:/gnupg\secring.gpg': file open error
gpg: keyblock resource `c:/gnupg\pubring.gpg': file open error
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `SA000146.asc': general error
gpg: import from `SA000146.asc' failed: general error
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

It seemed to me that the keywrings are not being found as the directory c:/gnupg does not exist. I changed the homedir to the one gpg is found as following:

```
E:\tdp\gpg>gpg --homedir E:\tdp\gpg
```

After this the same error appeared, even more I can not list the keys any more which I could list before this change?

How could I change the back to the default homedir? As well could you help me to import the gpg key? Since I am not very expierienced with this if possible explain the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So today I tried to copy all the gpg folder to the c: drive and rename that folder with as in the error. This helped me to import the key. and now I am able to list the keys as well.

Please do let me know if this is not the correct way how to deal with this.